# Detect build failure in container builder cloudbuild.yaml script

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-container-builder

We would like to communicate to an external system when we have a google cloud build failure, preferably directly from the cloudbuild.yaml (https://cloud.google.com/container-builder/docs/build-config) script where we today only notify on build success.

Build failures are shown in the container registry build history list but is it possible to detect these failures from cloudbuild.yaml and do something when they happen?

Comment: Have you tried configuring notification for [third party services](https://cloud.google.com/container-builder/docs/configure-third-party-notifications) using cloud functions, pub/sub?

Comment: Thank you, that solves my problem!

Comment: If you want to close this question, consider answering below.